# How to play webcam video in full screen mode using opencv and tkinter

Tags: opencv, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple GUI, in which the video feed from the webcam will be playing on the screen. But, I am unable to render the video to the full screen. Here is my code... As I am a beginner to tkinter, I don't know how to solve this at this point of time, help me out to know where am I wrong...

I am trying to make an face recognition tool by the above window. Because of that the full screen mode will be very much helpful....

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, screen_width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, screen_height)

root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
video_label = tk.Label()
video_label.pack()

def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    
    video_label.imgtk = imgtk
    video_label.configure(image=imgtk,height=screen_height,width=screen_width)
    video_label.after(10, show_frame)

root.state('zoomed')
show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see in the image, the video feed is leaving some parts on the screen, I want the video to be full screen;

[image]

Comment: `video_label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`?

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work

Comment: You need to resize the image either on `cv2image` using `cv2image = cv2.resize(cv2image, ...)` or `img` using `img = img.resize(...)`.